# Angular 2: Bind 2 child widgets via parent

Tags: angular

My question about binding of 2 child widgets via parent.

[image]

I have a chart with EventEmitter and a table with EventEmitter inside the parent component. Idea is to highlight the sector at chart on mouse hover on table. When I bind them like below, using extra EventEmitter at parent, my chart gets too much events, although the table emits only 1 event. I cheched that there is no obvious event cycling. Where I'm wrong?

```
<parent>
   <chart [sectorSelected]="parentEventEmitter" (hover)="selected = $event"></chart>
   <table (hover)="parentEventEmitter.emit($event)"></table>
</parent>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a stackblitz?

Comment: I'm afraid not, the code is secured.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have found the problem:
My chart was bound to a function, returning new list every time, so Angular I suppose creates new event binding for every entry, so there is was the mass effect.

**ALWAYS BIND YOUR COMPONENTS TO STATIC DATA COLLECTIONS!**